# R: make nomogram plot label italic

Tags: r

I am drawing a nomogram based on the dataset `PimaIndiansDiabetes` using the package `rms`:

```
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

library(rms)
ddist <- datadist(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
options(datadist='ddist')
lrm_model <- lrm (diabetes ~ .,
                  data = PimaIndiansDiabetes,
                  x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
nom <- nomogram(lrm_model,
                fun=plogis,
                fun.at=c(0.01, 0.05, seq(0.1, 0.9, by=0.2), 0.95, 0.99),
                abbrev = TRUE,
                lp=F,
                vnames = "labels",
                varname.label=TRUE,
                funlabel = "Diabetes")
plot(nom,
     fun.side=c(1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1),
     label.every=1,
     lmgp = 0.15,
     xfrac=.4
)
```

Below is the plot:

[image]

How do I make the axis names italic? (I actually prefer if only the 8 predictors' names are italic)

Comment: Nice question. Upvoted!  I found this to modify names but not font. Please read it  [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5451623/pdf/atm-05-10-211.pdf)